# ORA-00984: column not allowed here error while loading data

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am new to sql loader and trying to load data using sql loader. I am getting `column not allowed here` for following field

```
DR165_CREDIT_LIMIT_EXP_DT     POSITION (14692:14699)
"CASE WHEN :DR165_CREDIT_LIMIT_EXP_DT = '00000000' THEN NULL
WHEN :DR165_CREDIT_LIMIT_EXP_DT = BLANKS THEN NULL  else TO_DATE(TRIM(:DR165_CREDIT_LIMIT_EXP_DT), 'YYYYMMDD')END" ,
```

Could you please suggest what needs to be fixed? Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Didn't you try my answer to your other question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Oracle sqlldr: column not allowed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436033/oracle-sqlldr-column-not-allowed-here).  BLANKS is a sqlldr keyword and may not be used in that manner.  Try using `''` instead.

Also, considering that BLANKS is a string it should be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: ```DR165_CREDIT_LIMIT_EXP_DT         POSITION (14692:14699)  
"decode(TRIM(:DR165_CREDIT_LIMIT_EXP_DT),'', NULL, '00000000', NULL, TO_DATE(TRIM(:DR165_CREDIT_LIMIT_EXP_DT), 'YYYYMMDD'))",``` Still getting ```ORA-01843: not a valid month```

Comment: In my sqlldr scripts I am setting date like this - ```Po_Create_Date date "dd/Mon/yy"``` when source value is like 29-Mar-19.  Another option, can you insert the date without reformatting and then format it after its been loaded into database?

Comment: I am getting data as 00000016 and it is throwing ```not a valid month``` error. Most of the time, data is either ```00000000, blanks, 00000001 or 20190820```

Comment: You will need to use your ```CASE``` statement or some other means to remove values like 00000016 since this is an invalid date.

Comment: Thanks for kind help!